# after login redirect to page according to user_level problem

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

My apologies if this question has been covered previously but after trawling cannot seem to locate the answer.

My question is: Is there an easy way to redirect a user after immediately logging in according to their user level access to their own specific page? ie a person logs in who has admin access redirects to for example admin.php or similarly a visitor with a visitor access level is immediately redirected to acceuil.php

```
if(!empty($_POST["login"])){
    //Retrieve the field values from our login form.
    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    // $passwordAttempt = sha1($passwordAttempt);

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, role FROM users WHERE username = :username ";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pdo_statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT role FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password=:password ");
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();   

    if($user === false){
            die('Incorrect username !!');
    } else{
            //Compare the passwords.
            $validPassword = password_verify(($passwordAttempt), $user['password']);

            //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
            if(($passwordAttempt)===$user['password']){
                    //Provide the user with a login session.
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

                    header('Location: core/acceuil.php');
                    exit;                    
            } else {
                    //$validPassword was FALSE. Passwords do not match.
                    die(' password combination!');
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your screenshot, your passwords are not hashed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirect based on a `switch` of their role. Though, your current code is rather messy and does not appear to actually use `password_verify()` and you run multiple queries, so I've refactored it a bit.

```php
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST["login"])){
    //Retrieve the field values from our login form.
    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, role FROM users WHERE username = :username ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    ïf ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        //Provide the user with a login session.
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

        switch ($row['role']) {
            case 'admin':
                $url = 'admin.php';
                break;
            default:
                $url = 'acceuil.php';
        }

        header('Location: core/'.$url);
        exit; 
    } else {
        die('Incorrect username or password');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but the code don t work ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\stage\index.php on line 14

Comment: I can't spot any undefined rows in that code. Should work as-is.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
require 'core/connection.php';
if(!empty($_POST["login"])){
$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, role FROM users WHERE username = :username ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && password_verify($password, $row['password']))

Comment: i have tried $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) the code don't show me the message error but is always do Incorrect username or password

Comment: From your screenshot in the question (as I mentioned in the comments there), you don't seen to actually hash the password?

Comment: i used sha1 to hash the password same problem

Comment: Use `password_hash()` when inserting the password.